# Fragment Replacement Techniques

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have three fragments which are bound to Tabs as you swipe from TabA to TabB to TabC and it respectively loads FragA, FragB and FragC using ViewPager(Hope you understand this part). This swipe Tabs works just fine but I have a few fixed buttons attached to the bottom of the layout and when each button is clicked i want to load a new fragment to replace any of the Fragment A, B or C. The replacement works fine but when i return to the replaced/previous Fragment all the UI components on that layout completely disappears and it does not indicate if it has been paused, stopped or destroyed. Heres the Code:

Replacing previous Fragment Code:

```
        if(actionBar.isShowing())
                {
                    actionBar.hide();
                }
                FragmentManager fms = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fts = fms.beginTransaction();
                search s = new search();
                if(getCurrentDisplayFragment() == Type1)
                {
                    setcurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
                    Fragment frgs = mAdapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
                    viewPager.removeViewAt(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
                    frgs.setUserVisibleHint(false);

                    Log.i("if say", "Not Responding");
                }

                fts.replace(R.id.hoster, s);
                            fts.addToBackStack("search");
                fts.commit();
                setCurrentDisplayFragment(s,Type2);
```

The `setCurrentDisplayFragment(s,Type2);` i built that code to help indicate which fragment is being replaced and what measures to take. S is a Fragment and Type2 is a string

Thus when the back button is pressed i want to return back to any of the Fragments A, B or C  that was previously replaced.
Here is the code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onBackPressed();
        Log.i("event in back","I have been presssed ");
        if(getCurrentDisplayFragment() == Type2)
        {
            actionBar.show();
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            fm.popBackStack();
            ft.remove(getCurrentDisplayFragment(Type2));
            ft.commit();
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(getcurrentItem());
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(getcurrentItem());
            Fragment frags = mAdapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
            frags.setUserVisibleHint(true);
            setCurrentDisplayFragment(frags, Type1);
        }
        else
        {

        }

    }
```

Though some variable names and method declaration are not shown but you should get the picture of what am doing because all declarations have been done. its just The Replacement and retaining of their UI states thats giving me a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you complicating this so much? If you want to replace any of the fragments in the view pager, then just replace the view pager. It would be a lot easier if you would have a fragment holding the view pager with the tabs and when the bottom buttons are pressed, you just replace the fragment holding the view pager with the new fragment. In this way you won't need to do anything when the back button will be pressed.

Comment: The hoster is an id to a fragment encapsulating the viewpager.